# plugin on subpage required resource in subpage's directory

Tags: php, wordpress

resource Means (assets, image, icon and all misc)

i make a plugin which required a resource in `wordpress\wp-content\plugins\Hope_widget` when it is placed in home page, but when i set it in sub page then it required resource from its subpage's url. so fire me a error like 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) '

Example

subpage have link say `http://www.asdasd.com/itsTest` then resource found `http://www.asdasd.com/itsTest/wp-content/plugins/Hope_widget` but it should be `http://www.asdasd.com/wp-content/plugins/Hope_widget`

Please help me if you have some idea!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the WordPress [plugin reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url#Common_Usage), using:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png' , __FILE__ ) . '" > ';
?>
```

should output:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/wordpress.png">.
```

Removing the image tag and entering your required tag around it should fix your problem.

Comment: firefox gives
http://haltonhillsroofing.ca/wp-content/plugins/swfobject.js
instead of http://haltonhillsroofing.ca/wp-content/plugins/MY_PLUGIN_NAME/swfobject.js

Comment: Code for Linking is 

$message .='<script type="text/javascript" src="'.plugins_url('swfobject.js', '__FILE__').'"></script>';

Comment: here it is not FILE only it is _ _ File _ _

Comment: Did you try `dirname(__FILE__)`?

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `plugins_url('swfobject.js', __FILE__)` ??

Comment: that instead of `__FILES__`, see the link in my post (it's the second example